# Would connecting an amplified sound output to a line level input(aux cable) affect my car's stereo speakers negatively?

Tags: amplifier, speakers, sound, damage

My Bluetooth module has a built in amplifier and I connected the outputs to an aux cable and would like to plug it into my car radio, which also has a built in amplifier... I didn't think this was a problem before but it was brought to my attention on a previous question I had answered.

Comment: Match the signal levels with an attenuator.

Comment: it might actually work ok since inputs are usually high-impedance and car speakers are 4-8 ohms; yes the module provides  "too much juice", but the input doesn't draw much current either. they make audio transformers to use for this, but they are often just 1:1. try it on silence and ever-increasing volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on your definition of a problem and how well your car stereo is designed to handle over-voltage signal inputs and if your speakers are rated high enough to handle the sustained MAX power the amplifier can put out.

Chances are one of those is not, so yes you could easily blow the amp or tear a speaker.

Even if everything can handle it, it is still not a good idea.

The aux input is expecting millivolt signals, not volts. The amplifier with quickly rail-out, and all you are going to hear is a LOUD noise.

You COULD use a resistor divider to "de-amplify" the blue-tooth output before you feed it in, but you will get a loss of quality along the way.

Comment: Agreed, not a good idea. Another point - many amplifiers driving speakers or 'phones have Class-D (fast-switching) outputs of high amplitude, even for low volume. Not something a low-level auxiliary input might take well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got another Bluetooth module from one of those Bluetooth earpieces I had laying around and I don't think it amplifies the sound. I don't think it would need to amplify the signal to such a small mono speaker

Comment: @StarboiSeon you may want to start out connecting whatever you try through a potentiometer wound to the ground end initially and wind it up till the sound if acceptable. If you can go all the way to full volume on it you will not need a divider. If not, you can select resistors based on the POT setting.

Comment: I wish I had the resources and the technical know-how to do that... But I don't 